# Adding an unused SelectParameter makes query stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have a data source that is working fine:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description], [NonScrumStory].[CreatedDate], [DailyTaskHours].[Hours], [Application].[AppName], [SupportCatagory].[Catagory] FROM [NonScrumStory], [DailyTaskHours], [Application], [SupportCatagory] WHERE ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = @userIdSelected) AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) AND ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application])">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is displaying data to a gridview.

When I add another selectparameter:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="test" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

The gridview no longer shows anything...

What am I doing wrong?

I will be using the next parameter for a DeleteCommand query statement if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because it's not part of the `SelectCommand`. Modify your markup like this:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>

<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="test" Type="String" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

I don't know, from your question, whether or not you're using `userIdSelected` in the `DeleteCommand` so modify the markup appropriately.